# PHP how to come up with logic for score calculation project

Tags: php, sql, calculator

I'll start off by stating the simple rules for this project so you can follow along with the logic, Toto = 1 point and goal difference = 3 points
if a match outcome finishes at 2 - 0 and user predicts 3 - 1 they get a goal difference of 3 points.

The logic i am trying to implement relates to the program seeing this as a toto point, the toto works as if the match finishes 5 - 0 and you predict 1 - 0 you still get one point for guessing the right outcome, the problem is it works with a draw if a match finishes as a draw 3 - 3 and you predicted 1 - 1 you get toto of 1 point

here is the logic for the goal difference in php code

```
// check for goal diff bonus
    $goal_diff_bonus = Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'diffpoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_DIFFPOINTS, 'int' );
    if ( ! $full && $home != $away && ( $home - $user_home ) == ( $away - $user_away ) ) {
        $score += $goal_diff_bonus;
    }

    if ( $joker == 1 && $this->has_jokers ) $score *= Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'joker_multiplier', FOOTBALLPOOL_JOKERMULTIPLIER, 'int' );

    return $score;
```

and here is the current logic for the toto points

```
$full = false;
    $score = 0;
    // check for toto result
    if ( $this->is_toto_result( $home, $away, $user_home, $user_away ) == true ) {
        // check for exact match
        if ( $home == $user_home && $away == $user_away ) {
            $score = (int) Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'fullpoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_FULLPOINTS, 'int' );
            $full = true;
        } else {
            $score = (int) Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'totopoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_TOTOPOINTS, 'int' );
        }
    }
```

i am trying to make a draw which if the player guesses 1-1 and the outcome is anything from 5-5 or any other draw to be a goal difference of 3 points

to avoid any confusion toto is predicting the right outcome of a match

this code following needs to be able to take the home score and away score and the players home and away score and if they result in a draw it needs to give it a goal difference bonus so under this code it should have that functionality

```
// check for goal bonus
    $goal_bonus = Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'goalpoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_GOALPOINTS, 'int' );
    if ( $home == $user_home ) $score += $goal_bonus;
    if ( $away == $user_away ) $score += $goal_bonus;

    // check for goal diff bonus
    $goal_diff_bonus = Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'diffpoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_DIFFPOINTS, 'int' );
    if ( ! $full && $home != $away && ( $home - $user_home ) == ( $away - $user_away ) ) {
        $score += $goal_diff_bonus;
    }

    if ( $joker == 1 && $this->has_jokers ) $score *= Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'joker_multiplier', FOOTBALLPOOL_JOKERMULTIPLIER, 'int' );

    return $score;
}
```

also the same needs to be changed on the sql code for this function

```
SELECT 

                              0, %d AS score_type, m.play_date AS score_date, m.id AS match_id, u.ID AS user_id

                            , IF ( p.has_joker = 1, %d, 1 ) AS `score`

                            , IF ( m.home_score = p.home_score AND m.away_score = p.away_score, 1, NULL ) AS `full`

                            , IF ( m.home_score = p.home_score AND m.away_score = p.away_score, NULL, 

                                IF (

                                    IF ( m.home_score > m.away_score, 1, IF ( m.home_score = m.away_score, 3, 2 ) )

                                    =

                                    IF ( p.home_score > p.away_score, 1, IF ( p.home_score = p.away_score, 3, 2 ) )

                                    , IF ( p.home_score IS NULL OR p.away_score IS NULL, NULL, 1 )

                                    , NULL 

                                )

                              ) AS `toto`

                            , IF ( m.home_score = p.home_score, 

                                    IF ( m.away_score = p.away_score, 2, 1 ),

                                    IF ( m.away_score = p.away_score, 1, NULL )

                              ) AS `goal_bonus`

                            , IF( m.home_score = p.home_score AND m.away_score = p.away_score, NULL,

                                IF( 

                                    m.home_score <> m.away_score AND

                                    ( CAST( m.home_score AS SIGNED ) - CAST( p.home_score AS SIGNED ) ) 

                                    = 

                                    ( CAST( m.away_score AS SIGNED ) - CAST( p.away_score AS SIGNED ) )

                                    , 1, NULL 

                                )

                              ) AS `goal_diff_bonus`

                            , 0 AS `ranking`

                            , %d AS `ranking_id`

                        FROM {$wpdb->users} u 

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$prefix}matches m ON ( 1 = 1 )

                        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$prefix}predictions p

                            ON ( p.match_id = m.id AND ( p.user_id = u.ID OR p.user_id IS NULL ) )

                        WHERE m.home_score IS NOT NULL AND m.away_score IS NOT NULL AND u.ID IN ( {$user_ids} ) ";
```

the sql and the php scripts need to work together to make a draw score calculate to a goal difference bonus

Comment: Have you considered doing this Test Driven? This is a textbook example of something that would benefit a lot from TDD.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i am trying to make a draw which if the player guesses 1-1 and the outcome is anything from 5-5 or any other draw to be a goal difference of 3 points

Comment: I personally have problems following your explanation. I think it includes too much implicit knowledge. Try rephrasing it for people not knowing anything about toto. Best way would be to show a set of possible input states, and what the outputs should be.

Comment: Same here: I have a hard time understanding your question or where the problem lays. Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: this code following needs to be able to take the home score and away score and the players home and away score and if they result in a draw it needs to give it a goal difference bonus so under this code it should have that functionality

Comment: // check for goal diff bonus
  $goal_diff_bonus = Football_Pool_Utils::get_fp_option( 'diffpoints', FOOTBALLPOOL_DIFFPOINTS, 'int' );
  if ( ! $full && $home != $away && ( $home - $user_home ) == ( $away - $user_away ) ) {
   $score += $goal_diff_bonus;
  }

Comment: You need to try  to explain this in terms that someone who knows absolutely nothing about a football pool would understand